# ODR error: fcn does not output [n]-shaped array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to have a curve fit usign *scipy.odrpack* but i have encountered a problem with the command *odrpack.ODR*.
This is the code I wrote:

```
def f(x,i):
    return i[0]*numpy.exp(-i[1]*x)

a=pandas.read_csv("~/Untitled.csv")
exp=odrpack.Model(f)
data=odrpack.RealData(a['t'],a['c1'])
myodr=odrpack.ODR(data, exp, beta0=[1.,2.])
myoutput=myodr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

But i get the following error (10 is due to the array's length):

```
OdrError: fcn does not output [10]-shaped array
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?
Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't it be `def f(i, x)`?

Comment: You're right. I thought that the order wouldn't matter. Now it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have accidentally swapped the parameters of your fit function:

```
def f(x,i):
    return i[0]*numpy.exp(-i[1]*x)
```

when it should be

```
def f(i,x):  # note the order of arguments
    return i[0]*numpy.exp(-i[1]*x)
```